# Subtract aggregate from Pandas Series/Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Given the following table

```
   vals
0    20
1     3
2     2
3    10
4    20
```

I'm trying to find a clean solution in pandas to subtract away a value, say `30` for example, to end with the following result.

```
   vals
0     0
1     0
2     0
3     5
4    20
```

I was wondering if pandas had a solution to performing this that didn't require looping through all the rows in a dataframe, something that takes advantage of pandas's bulk operations.

Comment: Can you explain why subtracting 30 from your table gives you the shown output? What's the logic?

Comment: @Allen You start to consume 30 on the first row. 20 out of 30 used in row 0, 3 out of 30 in row 1, 2 out of 30 in row 2 and the remaining 5 on row 3. The row 4 remains the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- identify where cumsum is greater than or equal to 30
- mask the rows where it isn't
- reassign the one row to be the cumsum less 30

---

```
c = df.vals.cumsum()
m = c.ge(30)
i = m.idxmax()
n = df.vals.where(m, 0)
n.loc[i] = c.loc[i] - 30
df.assign(vals=n)

   vals
0     0
1     0
2     0
3     5
4    20
```

---

*Same thing, but `numpy`fied*

```
v = df.vals.values
c = v.cumsum()
m = c >= 30
i = m.argmax()
n = np.where(m, v, 0)
n[i] = c[i] - 30
df.assign(vals=n)

   vals
0     0
1     0
2     0
3     5
4    20
```

---

**Timing**

```
%%timeit 
v = df.vals.values
c = v.cumsum()
m = c >= 30
i = m.argmax()
n = np.where(m, v, 0)
n[i] = c[i] - 30
df.assign(vals=n)
10000 loops, best of 3: 168 µs per loop

%%timeit
c = df.vals.cumsum()
m = c.ge(30)
i = m.idxmax()
n = df.vals.where(m, 0)
n.loc[i] = c.loc[i] - 30
df.assign(vals=n)
1000 loops, best of 3: 853 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's one using NumPy with four lines of code -

```
v = df.vals.values
a = v.cumsum()-30
idx = (a>0).argmax()+1
v[:idx] = a.clip(min=0)[:idx]
```

Sample run -

```
In [274]: df     # Original df
Out[274]: 
   vals
0    20
1     3
2     2
3    10
4    20

In [275]: df.iloc[3,0] = 7  # Bringing in some variety

In [276]: df
Out[276]: 
   vals
0    20
1     3
2     2
3     7
4    20

In [277]: v = df.vals.values
     ...: a = v.cumsum()-30
     ...: idx = (a>0).argmax()+1
     ...: v[:idx] = a.clip(min=0)[:idx]
     ...: 

In [278]: df
Out[278]: 
   vals
0     0
1     0
2     0
3     2
4    20
```

Comment: thank you for reminding me about clip :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
#A one-liner solution
df['vals'] = df.assign(res = 30-df.vals.cumsum()).apply(lambda x: 0 if x.res>0 else x.vals if abs(x.res)>x.vals else x.vals-abs(x.res), axis=1)

df
Out[96]: 
   vals
0     0
1     0
2     0
3     5
4    20
```